# Gnome Dock Duplicates

Tags: 20.04, gnome

After system runs for a while, or goes to sleep the Gnome dock is relaunched. What steps do I take to resolve this other than reboot?

[image: Gnome Dock]

Comment: This is not normal behavior and I can't replicate this on a clean installation. Can you edit your question and provide a little more details about things you've added to changed on your system since the system was installed.  Particularly software that's not in repos or UI changes that aren't in the default system settings options. Since this doesn't happen on a clean install it's likely one of these things so it's hard to tell without knowing what else is on your device.